How can I retrofit covers on my soffit light cans to protect indoor bulbs?
I have been looking for lights to install in the recessed soffit fixtures on our porch. I found some very promising PAR38 bulbs from Philips that work great, but my understanding is that the fixture needs to be enclosed, it’s a standard HALO housing that is installed in the soffit. It seems very easy for moisture and/or bugs to get up into the house if I just screw these in.
These fit and work great, but the standard HALO fixture is exposed. I was trying to find some sort of trim with glass to enclose the light. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?
Edit:
While looking at the link above, it mentions these bulbs are meant for indoor use, but the pair I bought mention being used for floodlights.
I am open to options, but for some reason it is very difficult to find recessed lighting that has motion sensing functionality.

I see that the bulb is rated for indoor use. Seems like looking for an outdoor bulb would be simpler than trying to retrofit a cover, but unless you're regularly getting hurricane-type storms in your area I'd just use them. Folks have used common incandescent bulbs in soffit cans for decades. They work just fine.

Sorry the Philips site is very hard to find what I am looking for. I linked the bulb below.
Does the housing not need to be enclosed if it is outdoors?  Its a basic Halo housing in the soffit on the front porch.
https://www.doitbest.com/product/534313/philips-120w-equivalent-soft-white-par38-medium-motion-daylight-sensor-led-floodlight-light-bulb-534313/

I already updated your question with what I think is the right page. Put all information up there, please, not in a comment. Take the [tour].

NEC:

A receptacle is considered to be in a location protected from the weather when it is located under roofed open porches, canopies, marquees, or the like and where it will not be subjected to a beating rain or water runoff.

It may still be exposed to fog etc. so treat as a damp location (like a bathroom)

But this isn't a receptacle, is it?  (Not that I'm saying you're wrong.)

Yeah I am confused by this.  I basically am just trying to use a PAR38 Floodlight bulb, inside of a recessed HALO housing that is installed in the soffit ceiling of my front porch.  I am not sure if/how I can enclose that fixture so that the inside of the housing is not exposed.
